# Split Strings into columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a name field in Students table which is a comma separated string in format "LastName, FirstName, Middle Name".While doing a select statement in SQL query I need to break this up into separate fields.How can I achieve this in SQL?.Some times Middle intial won't be available.

```
SUBSTRING(Name,CHARINDEX(',',Name,1)+2,LEN(Name)) AS FirstName,
SUBSTRING(Name,1,CHARINDEX(',',Name,1)-1) AS LastName,
```

Above code works fine when there is no Middle name.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu 'eg: James, Billy, L'
'eg: James, Billy'

Comment: What about middle name then?

Comment: So it's Last Name (James), First Name (Billy), Middle Name (L) ?

Comment: @Ullas That is my problem

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Yes

Comment: charindex takes three arguments, search-exp, source-exp and start-index. So the solution can be little lengthy but not be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you need:

```
declare @tmp table (fullname varchar(100));
insert @tmp values('James, Billy, L'), ('John, Snow');

select
    fullname
    , [Last Name]
    , case
        when charindex(',', Remainder, 0) > 0
            then ltrim(substring(Remainder, 0, charindex(',', Remainder, 0)))
        else ltrim(Remainder)
    end [First Name]
    , case
        when charindex(',', Remainder, 0) = 0
            then NULL
        else ltrim(substring(Remainder, charindex(',', Remainder, 0) + 1, len(Remainder)))
    end [Middle Name]
from
(select
    fullname
    , substring(fullname, 0, charindex(',', fullname, 0))                       [Last Name]
    , substring(fullname, charindex(',', fullname, 0) + 1, len(fullname))       [Remainder]
from @tmp) result;
```

Answer (score 1):

First just find the occurrences of comma(,) in the string. Then use `CASE` expression to get the number of comma. If there is 2 comma then we can assume that middle name is also there. If 1 then only first name and last name. Then use the combinations of `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX` string functions.

**Query**

```
select t.name, 
left(
    t.name, 
    charindex(',', t.name, 1) - 1
) last_name,
case t.comma_num 
when 2
then substring(
         t.name, 
         charindex(',', t.name, 1) + 1, 
         len(name) - 
         (charindex(',', t.name, 1) + 1) - charindex(',', reverse(t.name), 1) + 1
)
when 1 
then right(
         t.name, 
         charindex(',', reverse(t.name), 1) - 1
)
else null end as first_name,
case t.comma_num 
when 2 
then right(
         t.name, charindex(',', reverse(t.name), 1) - 1
) 
else null end as middle_name
from (
    select name, 
    len(name) - len(replace(name, ',', '')) comma_num
    from [your_table_name]
)t;
```

**[Find demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/636322)**

Answer (score 0):

```
Use CTE and SUBSTRING AND CHARINDEX funntions 

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100) = 'James, Billy, L' 
--DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100) = 'James, '', L'  

;WITH _CTE ( SplitedNames ,RemainStr) AS
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Name,0,CHARINDEX(',',@Name)),
           SUBSTRING(@Name,CHARINDEX(',',@Name)+1,LEN(@Name))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',RemainStr) = 0 THEN RemainStr ELSE       
           SUBSTRING(RemainStr,0,CHARINDEX(',',RemainStr)) END, 
           CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',RemainStr) = 0 THEN '' ELSE   
           SUBSTRING(RemainStr,CHARINDEX(',',RemainStr)+1,LEN(RemainStr))  
           END
    FROM _CTE 
    WHERE RemainStr <> '' 
)

SELECT SplitedNames FROM _CTE
```

Comment: I already have a split function,But need this as Separate columns